# Dynamically filtering a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, exec

I am trying to filter a pandas data frame using thresholds for three columns

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [6, 2, 10, -5, 3],
                   "B" : [2, 5, 3, 2, 6],
                   "C" : [-5, 2, 1, 8, 2]})
df = df.loc[(df.A > 0) & (df.B > 2) & (df.C > -1)].reset_index(drop = True)

df
    A  B  C
0   2  5  2
1  10  3  1
2   3  6  2
```

However, I want to do this inside a function where the names of the columns and their thresholds are given to me in a dictionary. Here's my first try that works ok. Essentially I am putting the filter inside `cond` variable and just run it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [6, 2, 10, -5, 3],
                   "B" : [2, 5, 3, 2, 6],
                   "C" : [-5, 2, 1, 8, 2]})
limits_dic = {"A" : 0, "B" : 2, "C" : -1}
cond = "df = df.loc["
for key in limits_dic.keys():
    cond += "(df." + key + " > " + str(limits_dic[key])+ ") & "
cond = cond[:-2] + "].reset_index(drop = True)"
exec(cond)
df
    A  B  C
0   2  5  2
1  10  3  1
2   3  6  2
```

Now, finally I put everything inside a function and it stops working (perhaps `exec` function does not like to be used inside a function!):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [6, 2, 10, -5, 3],
                   "B" : [2, 5, 3, 2, 6],
                   "C" : [-5, 2, 1, 8, 2]})
limits_dic = {"A" : 0, "B" : 2, "C" : -1}
def filtering(df, limits_dic):
    cond = "df = df.loc["
    for key in limits_dic.keys():
        cond += "(df." + key + " > " + str(limits_dic[key])+ ") & "
    cond = cond[:-2] + "].reset_index(drop = True)"
    exec(cond)
    return(df)

df = filtering(df, limits_dic)
df
    A  B  C
0   6  2 -5
1   2  5  2
2  10  3  1
3  -5  2  8
4   3  6  2
```

I know that `exec` function acts differently when used inside a function but was not sure how to address the problem. Also, I am wondering there must be a more elegant way to define a function to do the filtering given two input: 1)`df` and 2)`limits_dic = {"A" : 0, "B" : 2, "C" : -1}`. I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: if you change the name of the result (`cond = "df2 = df.loc["` and `return(locals()['df2'])`) it works. i tried to add dicts to `exec` to no avail

Comment: For more information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you're trying to build a dynamic query, there are easier ways. Here's one using a list comprehension and `str.join`:

```
query = ' & '.join(['{}>{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in limits_dic.items()])
```

Or, using `f`-strings with python-3.6+,

```
query = ' & '.join([f'{k}>{v}' for k, v in limits_dic.items()])
```

```
print(query)

'A>0 & C>-1 & B>2'
```

Pass the query string to `df.query`, it's meant for this very purpose:

```
out = df.query(query)
print(out)

    A  B  C
1   2  5  2
2  10  3  1
4   3  6  2
```

#### What if my column names have whitespace, or other weird characters?

From pandas 0.25, you can wrap your column name in backticks so this works:

```
query = ' & '.join([f'`{k}`>{v}' for k, v in limits_dic.items()])
```

See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697536/pandas-query-function-not-working-with-spaces-in-column-names) for more.

---

You could also use `df.eval` if you want to obtain a boolean mask for your query, and then indexing becomes straightforward after that:

```
mask = df.eval(query)
print(mask)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

out = df[mask]
print(out)

    A  B  C
1   2  5  2
2  10  3  1
4   3  6  2
```

---

#### String Data

If you need to query columns that use string data, the code above will need a slight modification.

Consider (data from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50692578/4909087)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':list('MMMFFF'),
                   'height':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'age':[70,80,90,40,2,3]})

print (df)
  gender  height  age
0      M       4   70
1      M       5   80
2      M       4   90
3      F       5   40
4      F       5    2
5      F       4    3
```

And a list of columns, operators, and values:

```
column = ['height', 'age', 'gender']
equal = ['>', '>', '==']
condition = [1.68, 20, 'F']
```

The appropriate modification here is:

```
query = ' & '.join(f'{i} {j} {repr(k)}' for i, j, k in zip(column, equal, condition))
df.query(query)

   age gender  height
3   40      F       5
```

---

For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Comment: In f-strings you can use the shorthand {k!r} above, rather than {repr(k)}...helps in long expressions like above.

Comment: how to handle if there is multiple value for the same column

Comment: @Abhis What is that supposed to look like?

Comment: @cs95  What if my column name itself has some operators such as `C > D` and I want to compare two such columns. Should I be adding double quotes around each column name, and entire query in single quote?

Comment: @MasayoMusic I think you can add backticks to the column name like `\`C > D\`` from pandas 0.25

Comment: OK great, I've updated the answer anyway, I assume more folks would have the same question. Appreciate the comment.

Comment: That part about using a 'mask' answered a question I've had about how to combine 'query' with the selection of a subset of columns, when using 'loc' to avoid chained indexing.   Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to @coldspeed 's version:

```
conditions = None
for key, val in limit_dic.items():
    cond = df[key] > val
    if conditions is None:
        conditions = cond
    else:
        conditions = conditions & cond
print(df[conditions])
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I couldn't find a way to make the accepted answer work joining together `isin` conditions that referenced a python list defined in my code.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to both posted, that may or may not be more pythonic:

```
import pandas as pd
import operator
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [6, 2, 10, -5, 3],
                   "B": [2, 5, 3, 2, 6],
                   "C": [-5, 2, 1, 8, 2]})

limits_dic = {"A": 0, "B": 2, "C": -1}

# equiv to [df['A'] > 0, df['B'] > 2 ...]
loc_elements = [df[key] > val for key, val in limits_dic.items()]

df = df.loc[reduce(operator.and_, loc_elements)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How I do this without creating a string and `df.query`:

```
limits_dic = {"A" : 0, "B" : 2, "C" : -1}
cond = None

# Build the conjunction one clause at a time 
for key, val in limits_dic.items():
    if cond is None:
        cond = df[key] > val
    else:
        cond = cond & (df[key] > val)

df.loc[cond]

    A  B  C
0   2  5  2
1  10  3  1
2   3  6  2
```

Note the hard coded `(>, &)` operators (since I wanted to follow your example exactly).