# How to make an "and" operation in Pandas DataFrame with items in a list

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have lists of column names, the equal relations and conditions

```
column = ['height', 'age', 'gender']
equal = ['>', '>', '==']
condition = [1.68, 20, 'F']
```

And I want to select the data with specific conditions in pandas DataFrame,

```
df = df[(df['height']>1.68) & df['age']>20 & df['gender']=='F']
```

Is it possible to use the three lists above (columns, equality, and condition) for realizing the selction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for built conditions, but is necessary `if-else` condition for add `""` for strings values in `values`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':list('MMMFFF'),
                   'height':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'age':[70,80,90,40,2,3]})

print (df)
  gender  height  age
0      M       4   70
1      M       5   80
2      M       4   90
3      F       5   40
4      F       5    2
5      F       4    3

q = ' & '.join(['{}{}"{}"'.format(i,j,k) if isinstance(k, str) 
               else '{}{}{}'.format(i,j,k) for i, j, k in zip(column, equal, condition)])
print (q)
height>1.68 & age>20 & gender=="F"
```

Thank you @Yakym Pirozhenko for simplier solution:

```
q = ' & '.join(['{}{}{}'.format(i,j,repr(k)) for i, j, k in zip(column, equal, condition)])
print (q)
height>1.68 & age>20 & gender=='F'
```

---

```
df = df.query(q)
print (df)
  gender  height  age
3      F       5   40
```

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko - Thank you, actually seems `if-else` should be omit.

Comment: @coldspeed - Thanks.

Comment: `if-else` may be still handy if there are `NaN`s in the string column.

Comment: @user2583253 - You are welcome!