# Pandas query function not working with spaces in column names

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with spaces in column names. I am trying to use `query` method to get the results. It is working fine with 'c' column but getting error for 'a b'

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a b", "c"])
a["a b"] = [1,2,3,4]
a["c"] = [5,6,7,8]
a.query('a b==5')
```

For this I am getting this error:

```
a b ==5
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't want to fill up space with other characters like '_' etc.

There is one hack using pandasql to put variable name inside brackets example: **[a b]**

Answer (score 101, accepted):

From pandas `0.25` onward you will be able to escape column names with backticks so you can do

```py
a.query('`a b` == 5')
```

Comment: Simple and easy, great solution. Thanks!

Comment: also if a column has a string number '1', we need ``: a.query(' ` 1 ` == 5')

Comment: What if I have a list of column names ? I have a variable with the list of names, they have spaces between them. I tried different methods with backticks but they just don't work.

Answer (score 38):

#### Pandas 0.25+

As described [here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#other-enhancements):

> `DataFrame.query()` and `DataFrame.eval()` now supports quoting column
>   names with backticks to refer to names with spaces ([GH6508](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508))

So you can use:

```
a.query('`a b`==5')
```

#### Pandas pre-0.25

You cannot use `pd.DataFrame.query` if you have whitespace in your column name. Consider what would happen if you had columns named `a`, `b` and `a b`; there would be ambiguity as to what you require.

Instead, you can use `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df = df.loc[df['a b'] == 5]
```

Since you are only filtering rows, you can omit `.loc` accessor altogether:

```
df = df[df['a b'] == 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible yet. Check [github issue #6508](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508#issuecomment-283181667):

> Note that in reality **.query** is just a nice-to-have interface, in fact it has very specific guarantees, meaning its meant to parse like a query language, and not a fully general interface.

Reason is for `query` need string to be a valid python expression, so column names must be valid python identifiers.

Solution is [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['a b'] == 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the query method does not accept column name with empty space. In any case you can query the dataframe in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'a b':[1,2,3,4], 'c':[5,6,7,8]})
a[a['a b']==1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pandas.query function I would create a condition in this case to lookup values and where the condition is True. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a b", "c"])
a["a b"] = [1,2,3,5]
a["c"] = [5,6,7,8]
#a.query('a b==5') Remove the query because it cannot lookup columns with spaces in the name.

condition = a['a b'] == 5
print(a['a b'][condition])
```

```
output:

    3    5
```

We see that at index 3 your condition evaluates to True (if you want the specific index and not Series of Boolean values).

Answer (score 0):

Easier way:

```
df[
    (df['column name 1'] == 10)
    & (df['column name 2'] > 4)
]
```