# multiple sets of conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to run a query on a table that matches any of the following *sets* of conditions:

```
SELECT
id,
time
FROM
TABLE
WHERE
<condition1 is True> OR,
<condition2 is True> OR,
<condition3 is True> OR,
...
```

Each condition might look like:

```
id = 'id1' AND t > 20 AND t < 40
```

The values from each `WHERE` condition (`id`, `20`, `40` above) are rows in a pandas dataframe - that is 20k rows long.  I see two options that would technically work:

- make 20k queries to the database, one for each condition, and concat the result
- generate a (very long) query as above and submit

My question: what would be an idiomatic/performant way to accomplish this? 
I suspect neither of the above are appropriate approaches and this problem is somewhat difficult to google.

Comment: If you are really looking for the pandas way to do this, check out [Dynamically filtering a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925327/dynamically-filtering-a-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: @cs95 the db is postgres and too large/too much io to pull from the server.  It looks like I need to remove the pandas tag :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create a temporary table with columns id, t1, and t2 and put your 20k rows in there.  Then just join to this temporary table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE.id, time
FROM TABLE 
JOIN TEMP_TABLE T2 ON
TABLE.ID = T2.ID AND TABLE.T > T1 AND TABLE.T < T2;
```