# Building an expression in python dynamically

Tags: c#, python, expression, lambda-calculus

I want to build an expression and evaluate it in python. Basically I will have Rule ID for which I need to build a Trigger condition (T), LHS (L), RHS (R) in the form of expression.

All the data required to build the above 3 expression will be stored in a form of three tables in database. Let say,

1) Constant table - stores rule Id and constants along with their order

2) Operator table - stores rule Id and operators, prior operator along with their order

3) Variable table - stores rule Id and variables, prior operator along with their order

Tables data will be in form of

[image]

so based on the equation order id, I need to build T, L, R expression for the given RuleId.
For example: expression for the RuleId =3, T,L,R will be as follows

T : ( ! 2204) and ( ! 2204)

L : 2204

R :  2204 * 2.00000

Tried by building the expressions using stack, queue in C#, it worked fine.
Is there any other easy way exists in python to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar issue and cs95's solution on the related post worked for me:

[Dynamically filtering a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925327/dynamically-filtering-a-pandas-dataframe)

Basically, string parsing + eval() looks like a good option, or df.query() if you're using pandas already.